# h5py flipping dimensions of images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I've been working on building a machine learning algorithm to recognize images, starting by creating my own h5 database. I've been following [this](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html) tutorial, and it's been useful, but I keep running into one major error - when using OpenCV in the image processing section of the code, the program is unable to save the processed image because it keeps flipping the height and width of my images. When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "array+and+label+data.py", line 79, in <module>
   hdf5_file["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]
   File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
   File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
   File "/Users/USER/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 631, in __setitem__
   for fspace in selection.broadcast(mshape):
   File "/Users/USER/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/selections.py", line 299, in broadcast
   raise TypeError("Can't broadcast %s -> %s" % (target_shape, count))
   TypeError: Can't broadcast (1, 240, 320, 3) -> (1, 320, 240, 3)
```

My images are supposed to all be sized to 320 by 240, but you can see that this is being flipped somehow. Researching around has shown me that this is because OpenCV and NumPy use different conventions for height and width, but I'm not sure how to reconcile this issue within this code without patching my installation of OpenCV. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'm a relative newbie to Python and all its libraries (though I know Java well)!

Thank you in advance!

Edit: adding more code for context, which is very similar to what's in the tutorial under the "Load images and save them" code example.

The size of my arrays:

```
train_shape = (len(train_addrs), 320, 240, 3)
val_shape = (len(val_addrs), 320, 240, 3)
test_shape = (len(test_addrs), 320, 240, 3)
```

The code that loops over the image addresses and resizes them:

```
# Loop over training image addresses
  for i in range(len(train_addrs)):
     # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
     if i % 1000 == 0 and i > 1:
     print ('Train data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(train_addrs)))

     # read an image and resize to (320, 240)
     # cv2 load images as BGR, convert it to RGB
     addr = train_addrs[i]
     img = cv2.imread(addr)
     img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
     img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

     # save the image and calculate the mean so far
     hdf5_file["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]
     mean += img / float(len(train_labels))
```

Comment: provide more code and shapes of the image and ndarrays. i guess reshaping the numpy array should help. a good resource for broadcasting is in [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Thanks, @skrubber, I added some more code context. If you want to see complete code example that I followed, it's actually in the tutorial link above, if that's helpful!

Comment: are you rolling back the img's 2 axis as well? and i don't see exception handling in the tutorial. for which code snippet are you catching the exception?

Comment: I updated the error above to include the whole snippet - it occurs at the second to last line of the loop which saves the hdf5_file, "hdf5_file["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]"

Comment: An array sliced as None would mean that a new axis is being inserted and that is 1. so img with shape of 320,240 will turn into (1,320,240) as you can see on the shape it is being broadcast into. but the shape of hd5_file train_img is 240,320. In the tutorial case, it will work because row and column dims are same: 224. But in your case where the row and col dim aren't equal, it'll not. try with 320x320.

Comment: Hm, I see how that would skirt the issue, since it avoids the flipping of axes (which is why it works in the tutorial). Most of my images are rectangular, though, and so making them square would distort the images. Do you think there's a way to be able to keep them rectangular?

Comment: ok the resizing interpolation is INTER_CUBIC. from the documentation, it is a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood. i sense this is incorrect for your dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Researching around has shown me that this is because OpenCV and NumPy use different conventions for height and width

Not exactly. The only thing that is tricky about images is 2D arrays/matrices are indexed with (row, col) which is opposite from normal Cartesian coordinates (x, y) that we might use for images. Because of this, sometimes when you specify points in OpenCV functions, it wants them in (x, y) coordinates---and similarly, it wants the dimensions of the image to be specified in (w, h) instead of (h, w) like an array would be made. And this is the case inside OpenCV's `resize()` function. You're passing it in (h, w) but it actually wants (w, h). From the [docs for `resize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize):

> **dsize** – output image size; if it equals zero, it is computed as:
>
> ```
> dsize = Size(round(fx*src.cols), round(fy*src.rows))
> ```
>
> Either `dsize` or both `fx` and `fy` must be non-zero.

So you can see here that the number of columns is the first dimension (the width) and the number of rows is the second (the height).

The simple fix is just to swap your (h, w) to (w, h) inside the `resize()` function:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (240, 320), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Comment: That was SO SIMPLE, and it totally worked!! Thank you so much, Alexander! I appreciate your explanation on indexing, as well, that made a lot of sense. Thanks :)